# eclipselink struct fields order

Tags: java, oracle, struct, eclipselink

I am working on a EclipseLink application, which uses Oracle Objects as IN and OUT parameters (while invoking stored procedure). As you know we have @Struct annotations available in Eclipselink for representing Oracle Object, I used it and it is working perfectly. But, looks like order of the fields declared in Struct annotated class matters a lot to map to correct field in oracle object. This causes maintenance issues and very difficult to code when object's properties are more. Is there a way in Eclipselink to say map Structure fields based on name and not with order.

Ex: Below is my Struct class. If by chance I declare variables in different order from fields list, wrong/incorrect mappings will happen while fetching records from stored proc. Its always mapping values to fields from top to bottom. @Column name annotation is not able to solve this issue.

```
        @Struct(name = "REC_OBJECT",
            fields = {"TRANS_ID", "PROJECT_ID", "LANGUAGE_CODE", "DESCRIPTION"})
    @Embeddable
    public class Master {

        @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
        private String projectId;

        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(name = "TRANS_ID")
        private String transactionId;

        @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_CODE")
        private String languageCode;

        @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;

}
```

Please suggest solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the dilemma - The 'fields' element is used to define an ordering different from how the fields/properties are processed in the entity. This is how you specify the order to match your Struct independently from how the properties in the entity are processed.

Comment: I thought the same (fields element is used to define the order and we can just map each field name to a property wherever we want in entity class using @Column annotation). But when I declare variables in entity class in different order from fields order, wrong mapping occurred. In the sense - in above code TRANS_ID is first field name in fields array. If I declare projectId as a first property instead of transactionId in entity class, TRANS_ID value is populated in propertyId. Hope you understand. is there anywhere I am doing wrong. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I have update code to move projectId as first property. Now when I receive results, TRANS_ID value is mapped to projectId property.

Comment: Any one has suggestions on this?